# Error: FractionallySizedBox has NaN values in minHeight and maxHeight

Tags: flutter, dart

The application throws an error log when I use the FractionallySizedBox (chart_bar.dart) widget. If I comment FractionallySizedBox widget then the application run success. I also try to search but don't understand and don't know why have that error. Please help me to determine why the error is and how to fix it.

Thanks in advance!

Error log:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
✓  Built build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk.
Connecting to VM Service at ws://127.0.0.1:33365/_nXykgS8z4E=/ws

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
BoxConstraints has NaN values in minHeight and maxHeight.

These invalid constraints were provided to RenderDecoratedBox's layout() function by the following function, which probably computed the invalid constraints in question:
RenderBox.layout

The offending constraints were: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=Infinity, NaN<=h<=NaN; NOT NORMALIZED)
The relevant error-causing widget was
FractionallySizedBox
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      BoxConstraints.debugAssertIsValid.<anonymous closure>.throwError
#1      BoxConstraints.debugAssertIsValid.<anonymous closure>
#2      BoxConstraints.debugAssertIsValid
#3      RenderObject.layout
#4      RenderBox.layout
#5      RenderFractionallySizedOverflowBox.performLayout
#6      RenderObject.layout
#7      RenderBox.layout
#8      ChildLayoutHelper.layoutChild
#9      RenderFlex._computeSizes
#10     RenderFlex.performLayout
#11     RenderObject.layout
#12     RenderBox.layout
#13     ChildLayoutHelper.layoutChild
#14     RenderFlex._computeSizes
#15     RenderFlex.performLayout
#16     RenderObject.layout
#17     RenderBox.layout
#18     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#19     RenderObject.layout
#20     RenderBox.layout
#21     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#22     RenderObject.layout
#23     RenderBox.layout
#24     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#25     RenderCustomPaint.performLayout
#26     RenderObject.layout
#27     RenderBox.layout
#28     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#29     _RenderCustomClip.performLayout
#30     RenderObject.layout
#31     RenderBox.layout
#32     RenderPadding.performLayout
#33     RenderObject.layout
#34     RenderBox.layout
#35     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#36     RenderObject.layout
#37     RenderBox.layout
#38     ChildLayoutHelper.layoutChild
#39     RenderFlex._computeSizes
#40     RenderFlex.performLayout
#41     RenderObject.layout
#42     RenderBox.layout
#43     _RenderSingleChildViewport.performLayout
#44     RenderObject.layout
#45     RenderBox.layout
#46     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#47     RenderObject.layout
#48     RenderBox.layout
#49     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#50     RenderObject.layout
#51     RenderBox.layout
#52     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#53     RenderObject.layout
#54     RenderBox.layout
#55     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#56     RenderObject.layout
#57     RenderBox.layout
#58     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#59     RenderObject.layout
#60     RenderBox.layout
#61     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#62     RenderObject.layout
#63     RenderBox.layout
#64     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#65     RenderObject.layout
#66     RenderBox.layout
#67     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#68     RenderCustomPaint.performLayout
#69     RenderObject.layout
#70     RenderBox.layout
#71     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#72     RenderObject.layout
#73     RenderBox.layout
#74     MultiChildLayoutDelegate.layoutChild
#75     _ScaffoldLayout.performLayout
#76     MultiChildLayoutDelegate._callPerformLayout
#77     RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox.performLayout
#78     RenderObject.layout
#79     RenderBox.layout
#80     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#81     RenderObject.layout
#82     RenderBox.layout
#83     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#84     _RenderCustomClip.performLayout
#85     RenderObject.layout
#86     RenderBox.layout
#87     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#88     RenderObject.layout
#89     RenderBox.layout
#90     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#91     RenderObject.layout
#92     RenderBox.layout
#93     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#94     RenderObject.layout
#95     RenderBox.layout
#96     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#97     RenderObject.layout
#98     RenderBox.layout
#99     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#100    RenderObject.layout
#101    RenderBox.layout
#102    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#103    RenderObject.layout
#104    RenderBox.layout
#105    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#106    RenderObject.layout
#107    RenderBox.layout
#108    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#109    RenderObject.layout
#110    RenderBox.layout
#111    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#112    RenderObject.layout
#113    RenderBox.layout
#114    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#115    RenderObject.layout
#116    RenderBox.layout
#117    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#118    RenderObject.layout
#119    RenderBox.layout
#120    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#121    RenderObject.layout
#122    RenderBox.layout
#123    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#124    RenderObject.layout
#125    RenderBox.layout
#126    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#127    RenderObject.layout
#128    RenderBox.layout
#129    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#130    RenderObject.layout
#131    RenderBox.layout
#132    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#133    RenderObject.layout
#134    RenderBox.layout
#135    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#136    RenderOffstage.performLayout
#137    RenderObject.layout
#138    RenderBox.layout
#139    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#140    RenderObject.layout
#141    RenderBox.layout
#142    _RenderTheatre.performLayout
#143    RenderObject.layout
#144    RenderBox.layout
#145    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#146    RenderObject.layout
#147    RenderBox.layout
#148    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#149    RenderObject.layout
#150    RenderBox.layout
#151    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#152    RenderObject.layout
#153    RenderBox.layout
#154    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#155    RenderCustomPaint.performLayout
#156    RenderObject.layout
#157    RenderBox.layout
#158    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#159    RenderObject.layout
#160    RenderBox.layout
#161    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#162    RenderObject.layout
#163    RenderBox.layout
#164    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#165    RenderObject.layout
#166    RenderBox.layout
#167    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#168    RenderObject.layout
#169    RenderBox.layout
#170    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#171    RenderObject.layout
#172    RenderBox.layout
#173    RenderView.performLayout
#174    RenderObject._layoutWithoutResize
#175    PipelineOwner.flushLayout
#176    RendererBinding.drawFrame
#177    WidgetsBinding.drawFrame
#178    RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback
#179    SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback
#180    SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame
#181    SchedulerBinding.scheduleWarmUpFrame.<anonymous closure>
(elided 4 frames from class _RawReceivePortImpl, class _Timer, and dart:async-patch)
The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired: RenderFractionallySizedOverflowBox#684cb relayoutBoundary=up20 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
RenderObject: RenderFractionallySizedOverflowBox#684cb relayoutBoundary=up20 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
    parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); flex=null; fit=null (can use size)
    constraints: BoxConstraints(unconstrained)
    size: MISSING
    alignment: Alignment.center
    textDirection: ltr
    widthFactor: pass-through
    heightFactor: 0.0
    child: RenderDecoratedBox#50904 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
        parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0)
        constraints: MISSING
        size: MISSING
        decoration: BoxDecoration
            color: MaterialColor(primary value: Color(0xff9c27b0))
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)
        configuration: ImageConfiguration(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#c381e(), devicePixelRatio: 2.8, locale: en_US, textDirection: TextDirection.ltr, platform: android)
        child: RenderLimitedBox#01777 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
            parentData: <none>
            constraints: MISSING
            size: MISSING
            maxWidth: 0.0
            maxHeight: 0.0
            child: RenderConstrainedBox#dcfaa NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
                parentData: <none>
                constraints: MISSING
                size: MISSING
                additionalConstraints: BoxConstraints(biggest)
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderFractionallySizedOverflowBox#684cb relayoutBoundary=up20 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 2001 pos 12: 'hasSize'

The relevant error-causing widget was
Column
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

FIle source code:
**main.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_complete_guide/models/transaction.dart';
import 'package:flutter_complete_guide/widgets/chart.dart';
import 'package:flutter_complete_guide/widgets/new_transaction.dart';
import 'package:flutter_complete_guide/widgets/transaction_list.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Personal Expenses',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.purple,
        accentColor: Colors.amber,
        fontFamily: 'Quicksand',
        textTheme: ThemeData.light().textTheme.copyWith(
              titleLarge: const TextStyle(
                fontFamily: 'OpenSans',
                fontSize: 20,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
        appBarTheme: const AppBarTheme(
          titleTextStyle: TextStyle(
            fontFamily: 'OpenSans',
            fontSize: 20,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final List<Transaction> _userTransactions = [
    // Transaction(
    //     id: 't1', title: 'New Shoes', amount: 69.99, date: DateTime.now()),
    // Transaction(
    //     id: 't2', title: 'Weekly Grociers', amount: 16.53, date: DateTime.now())
  ];

  List<Transaction> get _recentTransactions {
    return _userTransactions.where((tx) {
      return tx.date.isAfter(
        DateTime.now().subtract(
          Duration(days: 7),
        ),
      );
    }).toList();
  }

  void _addNewTransaction(String txTitle, double txAmount) {
    final newTx = Transaction(
        id: DateTime.now().toString(),
        title: txTitle,
        amount: txAmount,
        date: DateTime.now());

    setState(() {
      _userTransactions.add(newTx);
    });
  }

  void _startAddNewTransaction(BuildContext ctx) {
    showModalBottomSheet(
        context: ctx,
        builder: (_) {
          return GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {},
            behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
            child: NewTransaction(_addNewTransaction),
          );
        });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Personal Expenses'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () => _startAddNewTransaction(context),
            icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
            // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: [
              Chart(_userTransactions),
              TransactionList(_userTransactions),
            ]),
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () => _startAddNewTransaction(context),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**transaction_list.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_complete_guide/models/transaction.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

class TransactionList extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Transaction> transactions;

  const TransactionList(this.transactions, {super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 300,
      child: transactions.isEmpty
          ? Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  'No transactions added yet!',
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleLarge,
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 200,
                  child: Image.asset(
                    'assets/images/waiting.png',
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            )
          : ListView.builder(
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Card(
                  child: Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          vertical: 10,
                          horizontal: 15,
                        ),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border.all(
                            color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                            width: 2,
                          ),
                        ),
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                        child: Text(
                          '\$${transactions[index].amount.toStringAsFixed(2)}',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontSize: 20,
                              color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text(
                            transactions[index].title,
                            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleLarge,
                          ),
                          Text(
                            DateFormat.yMMMd().format(transactions[index].date),
                            style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                          )
                        ],
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              },
              itemCount: transactions.length,
            ),
    );
  }
}
```

**new_transaction.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_complete_guide/models/transaction.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

class TransactionList extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Transaction> transactions;

  const TransactionList(this.transactions, {super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 300,
      child: transactions.isEmpty
          ? Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  'No transactions added yet!',
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleLarge,
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 200,
                  child: Image.asset(
                    'assets/images/waiting.png',
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            )
          : ListView.builder(
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Card(
                  child: Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          vertical: 10,
                          horizontal: 15,
                        ),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border.all(
                            color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                            width: 2,
                          ),
                        ),
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                        child: Text(
                          '\$${transactions[index].amount.toStringAsFixed(2)}',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontSize: 20,
                              color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text(
                            transactions[index].title,
                            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleLarge,
                          ),
                          Text(
                            DateFormat.yMMMd().format(transactions[index].date),
                            style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                          )
                        ],
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              },
              itemCount: transactions.length,
            ),
    );
  }
}
```

**chart.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_complete_guide/models/transaction.dart';
import 'package:flutter_complete_guide/widgets/chart_bar.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

class Chart extends StatelessWidget {
  Chart(this.recentTransactions, {super.key});

  final List<Transaction> recentTransactions;

  List<Map<String, Object>> get groupedTransactionValues {
    return List.generate(7, (index) {
      final weekDay = DateTime.now().subtract(
        Duration(days: index),
      );
      var totalSum = 0.0;

      for (var i = 0; i < recentTransactions.length; i++) {
        if (recentTransactions[i].date.day == weekDay.day &&
            recentTransactions[i].date.month == weekDay.month &&
            recentTransactions[i].date.year == weekDay.year) {
          totalSum += recentTransactions[i].amount;
        }
      }

      return {
        'day': DateFormat.E().format(weekDay).substring(0, 1),
        'amount': totalSum,
      };
    });
  }

  double get totalSpending {
    return groupedTransactionValues.fold(0.0, (sum, item) {
      return sum + (item['amount'] as double);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      elevation: 6,
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
      child: Row(
        children: groupedTransactionValues.map((data) {
          return ChartBar(
            label: data['day'].toString(),
            spendingAmount: data['amount'] as double,
            spendingPctOfTotal: totalSpending == 0.0
                ? 0.0
                : (data['amount'] as double) / totalSpending,
          );
        }).toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**chart_bar.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ChartBar extends StatelessWidget {
  final String label;
  final double spendingAmount;
  final double spendingPctOfTotal;

  ChartBar(
      {required this.label,
      required this.spendingAmount,
      required this.spendingPctOfTotal});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Text('\$${spendingAmount.toStringAsFixed(0)}'),
        SizedBox(
          height: 4,
        ),
        Container(
          height: 60,
          width: 10,
          child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                  border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey, width: 1.0),
                  color: const Color.fromRGBO(220, 220, 220, 1),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
        FractionallySizedBox(
          heightFactor: spendingPctOfTotal,
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 4,
        ),
        Text(label),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Seems snippet just missing `Transaction` to complete the project :)

Comment: @YeasinSheikh: List<Transaction> _userTransactions in file main.dart ,if I uncomment the application still an error by the FractionallySizedBox widget

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistake in code chart_bar.dart

```
FractionallySizedBox(
                heightFactor: spendingPctOfTotal,
```

must be the same level with

```
Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
```

this is the right code and will run successfully

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ChartBar extends StatelessWidget {
  final String label;
  final double spendingAmount;
  final double spendingPctOfTotal;

  ChartBar(
      {required this.label,
      required this.spendingAmount,
      required this.spendingPctOfTotal});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Text('\$${spendingAmount.toStringAsFixed(0)}'),
        const SizedBox(
          height: 4,
        ),
        Container(
          height: 60,
          width: 10,
          child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                  border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey, width: 1.0),
                  color: const Color.fromRGBO(220, 220, 220, 1),
                ),
              ),
              FractionallySizedBox(
                heightFactor: spendingPctOfTotal,
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          height: 4,
        ),
        Text(label),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```